# Focus element which appears on focus of some other element on tab press

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with multiple table rows (tr elements). When I hover or focus on a table row, an actions menu button appears. If I navigate to a table row using the tab key, I can see the actions menu button. However, when I press the tab again, the focus is lost on the table row, causing the actions menu button to disappear. Is there a way to ensure that when I press the tab again, the focus shifts directly to the actions menu button?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Attribute Tabindex

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr tabindex="1">
            <th>title 1</th>
            <th>title 2</th>
            <th>title 3</th>
            <th>title 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr tabindex="2">
            <td>item</td>
            <td>item</td>
            <td>item</td>
            <td>item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr tabindex="3">
            <td>item</td>
            <td>item</td>
            <td>item</td>
            <td>item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr tabindex="4">
            <td>item</td>
            <td>item</td>
            <td>item</td>
            <td>item</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```